# Is my product proof for limits correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I wish to prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

Let $L_1 = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $L_2 = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ (we assume both limits exist), where

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_1 > 0 : (0 < |x-a| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - L_1| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(\epsilon + |L_2|)})$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_2 > 0 : (0 < |x-a| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x) - L_2| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(\epsilon + |L_1|)})$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_3 > 0 : (0 < |x-a| < \delta_3 \implies |g(x) - L_2| < \epsilon)$

We wish to show that

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : (0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)g(x) - L_1L_2| < \epsilon)$

By regrouping and then using the triangle inequality, we see that

$$\begin{align}
|f(x)g(x) - L_1L_2| &= |f(x)g(x) - L_1g(x) + L_1g(x) - L_1L_2| \\
&= |g(x)(f(x) - L_1) + L_1(g(x) - L_2)| \\
&\leq |g(x)||f(x)-L_1| + |L_1||g(x)-L_2|
\end{align}$$

Next, when $0 < |x-a| < \delta_3$, the triangle inequality lets us see that

$$|g(x)| = |g(x) - L_2 + L_2| \leq |g(x) - L_2| + |L_2| < \epsilon + |L_2|$$

So then if we set $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3)$, we conclude

$$\begin{align}
|g(x)||f(x)-L_1| + |L_1||g(x)-L_2| &< |g(x)||f(x)-L_1| + (\epsilon + |L_1|) \cdot |g(x)-L_2| \\
&< (\epsilon + |L_2|) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2(\epsilon + |L_2|)} + (\epsilon + |L_1|) \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2(\epsilon + |L_1|)} \\
&= \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align}$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks very nice! :-) (for the sake of completeness, say after defining delta : "we conclude that for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$")